# Fetching data using mysqli fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some trouble fetching some data from a database using MySQLi, I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, already tried quite a few different ways of calling stuff out of the table and nothing seems to be doing it.

it's been a while since i've coded php, i'm still trying to get my head around the MySQli changes.

Here's what I get when I run my code -

```
Connected successfully
Could not successfully run query (SELECT * FROM articles) from DB:
```

here's the code -

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php');
//global $config;
$security_check = 1;

if(!isset($security_check))
{
    echo "This is restricted directory";
    exit();
}

function viewarticles()
{
    global $config;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($config['hostname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Connected successfully";
        echo "<br/>";

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";
    $result = $conn->query($sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);


    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }

    // While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
    // Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
    // Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
    //       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $result->title;
    }

    $result->free();

    $conn->close();



}    

viewarticles();

?>
```

Comment: Does it returs a error code?

Comment: You need to specify the database, you also can't mix and match mysql_* and mysqli_* functions.

Comment: Parameter 4 of `new mysqli(..,..,..,'databasename')`